# Minimum timeout value for select() call

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am working on the system where low-latency is required for the network communication. The task is to check the existence of a particular host with a given port in minimal time.

I tried doing it with connect() call, it was working fine for local systems.But now when I tested it regressively for remote systems, it blocks for about 19-20 seconds. When I use select() call with some timeout value (I tested for 2 sec) it works fine. But I need to take the minimal value of this timeout that I can set as permanent for the system, but I am not sure what value can be the safest.

Comment: Two seconds is about as low as you can sensibly go, unless you can show that the remote host always responds within some shorter interval if it's up.

Comment: hmm... I am thinking of keeping that as 2-2.5 sec only. It'll need a bit more testing.

Comment: This all boils down to knowing the system (What's a remote system, across a building or half-way across the world!?). Without knowing the system architecture no-one can answer this for you.

Comment: I would say don't go below 5sec minimum.  Network latency, especially over long distances, can easily eat up that time.